# FreeMarker _TemplateModelException extended_hash+string

Tags: java, spring-boot, freemarker

I ran into this error in freemarker it was working ok but now is giving me this, I am using last version from spring starter io. I don't think is need an update. I can't figure out this is a Bug or error from my code.

**Error**

> freemarker.core._TemplateModelException: An error has occurred when reading existing sub-variable "daysOfTheWeek"; see cause exception! The type of the containing value was: extended_hash+string (com.mikedev.HRMSystem.model.Schedule wrapped into f.e.b.StringModel)

**Entity filed List**

```
@Column(name= "day_of_the_week")
@ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class)
private List<String> daysOfTheWeek;
```

**FreeMarker expresion**

```
<#if schedule.daysOfTheWeek?seq_contains("sunday")>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem it was from spring not from freemarker in ElemeantCollection need to add FetchType.EAGER to work it's seem spring don't have access to daysOfTheWeek because it close JPA connection